# How reliable is the booking site Trazy?

Tags: online-resources, bookings

Does anyone have experience with using a site called Trazy for activity booking?

https://www.trazy.com/things-to-do/seoul/all-category

I am trying to book tickets for some attractions in Seoul (from within Korea), and Trazy seems to have tickets at discounted prices

Is this website reliable? If I choose Korean Bank transfer as the payment option, it says I have to send them a scan of the transfer receipt and they will confirm my booking, and it has to be done within 24 hours. So it seems they confirm payment manually which to me just doesn't feel like it's practically doable (I mean, wouldn't they get a lot of bookings every day? How would they keep track of who booked what? Moreover when I booked tickets for two different attractions, the bank account number they showed me for money transfer was the same. How would they know what attraction I was trying to pay for?)

They come up as one of the first results of a google search for online ticket booking in Seoul, so I don't think it is a scam, but I wanted to get an idea of how reliable they are. Has anybody here used their service? Will there possibly be any hassle in getting the tickets at the attraction if I book through them? I would like to know from someone who has experience using their service.

Answer (score 4):

After personally using it I have found it to be reliable

After you have paid the ticket fees you will get vouchers through the mail; all you have to do is show the voucher (a printout will do) at the ticket booth at the attraction and an ID

However, you should keep in mind that a lot of the discount tickets on the site might have restrictions (non refundable after a certain date, can only be used on a particular day, only available to foreigners, and so you might be asked to show your passport or some other form of photo ID that shows you are not a Korean citizen, etc)

Summary: the site was reliable and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just let you know my experience with Trazy.com at Thailand.  We've booked for Phi Phi Island tour with them, booking and payment have been confirmed. However early in the morning we are waiting for the pickup at our hotel's lobby, then we've received an email from them saying that, their website has been in error, we have to book 3 days in advance!!!! They have destroyed our trip and plan.

So, be careful when you make any booking with them.  To me, this is a scam!!!!